# Styling the last-child of a React list

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm  trying to style a list of items in React, with a specific styling for the last item of this list.

Here is what I have for the moment

```
const SuggestionStyles: CSSProperties = {
  borderBottom: '1px solid #ccc',
};
// ...
{suggestions.map((suggestion: GeocodingSuggestion) => {
  return(
    <p style={SuggestionStyles} key={suggestion.name}>{suggestion.name}</p>
  );
})}
```

So not using any particular library to handle the styling right now. And I can't manage to find how to target the last child within `SuggestionStyles`

Answer (score 0):

Change `style={SuggestionStyles}` to:

`style={suggestions.indexOf(suggestion) === suggestions.length - 1 ?  SuggestionStyles : null}`

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options:

1. Use the  [`:last-child`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp) [css](/questions/tagged/css) selector, something like:

   ```css
   .container > p:last-child {
     color: red;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="container">
     <p>Paragraph 1</p>
     <p>Paragraph 2</p>
     <p>Paragraph 3</p>
   </div>
   ```
2. We can use the current index of [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to check if we're at the last element and apply any css accordingly:

   ```
   {suggestions.map((suggestion, index) => {
     const style = (index === suggestions.length - 1) ? { borderBottom: '1px solid #ccc' } : '';
     return(
       <p style={style} className={className} key={suggestion.name}>{suggestion.name}</p>
     );
   })}
   ```

   If you've already got a styling object, we can [*merge*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically) them with the new one:

   ```
   const style = (index === suggestions.length - 1) ? {...defaultStyling, ...{ borderBottom: '1px solid #ccc' } } : defaultStyling;
   ```